# Populate a table with empty and correct data with ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm triying to display some data from an returned array in a $http.get request, but the problem is that some parts of the data is empty that's because for some of the employees are existing records for some others no

something like this

```
data = [
  {'name':'Peter',age:'32',sex:'male'},
  {'name':'Josh',age:44}...
]
```

I tried to create empty array to fill the empty cells but those seens to work

```
let ordened_list = response.data
$scope.total_list = ordened_list.map(items=>{
  return {
     name:     items.name,
     lastname: items.lastname,
     age:      items.age,
     sex:      items.sex
})
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="(key,valores) in set_array | filter:buscarEmpleado | groupBy : 'nombre' ">
 <td class="text-left">{{key}}</td>
 <td class="text-right" ng-repeat="ft in valores | filter:{rubro_cod:'1'}">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ft.valor|number:2}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So what is not working? The JS or the HTML? If your question isn’t about a compiler error, ensure that there are no compile-time errors. (The `.map` as written has mis-matched curly brackets).

Comment: My JS, the problem was that i was no filtering well the data.